# Problem applying user-defined function to perform t-test on range of variables in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, lapply, t-test

I have a user-defined function that calculates a t-test by group, but having some trouble applying iteratively over a range of variables

```
require(dplyr)
require(rstatix)
require(purrr)

# make df 
set.seed(0)
mydf <- data.frame("category" = as.factor(sample(c("type1", "type2"), 50, replace = TRUE)),
                   "var1" = runif(50, min = 0, max = 100),
                   "var2" = runif(50, min = 50, max = 150))

# t test function (works)
my_t_test <- function(dataset, parameter, grouping_variable) {
  formula <- do.call("~", list(rlang::enexpr(parameter), rlang::enexpr(grouping_variable)))
  parameter <- dataset %>% t_test(formula, paired = FALSE, detailed = TRUE) %>% add_significance()
  return(parameter)
}

# apply to one var (gives desired output)
my_t_test(mydf, var1, category)
```

Now the problem. I would like to do for all vars:

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2")
trial <- lapply(mydf[ , vars], my_t_test, grouping_variable = category) #try 1 w/ lapply
tests <- map(vars, ~my_t_test(mydf, .x, category)) # try 2 w map
```

Errors in each case. With lapply I get:
" Error in UseMethod("pull") :
no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".

With map function I get:
"Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `pull()`:
! Can't extract columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `.x` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred."

Interested in learning more about both approaches.

Comment: If you're using sample, you need to add a seed. Add `set.seed(0)` to the beginning of your code :-)

Comment: Working with this to start as it is so simple and works well. One problem remaining is that the output does not preserve the name of the input variable, so I get a large tibble (depending on number of variables) but can't easily tell which variable goes with which list item. Is there any way to track this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is to iterate over a list of names instead of strings. Note that we can use `rlang::new_formula` to create formulas based on quoted variable names.

Below I use `map(set_names(vars), as.name)` to create a named list of variable names (`symbols`). Naming the list with `set_names()` is helpful when we look at the output which keeps the names.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
library(purrr)

my_t_test <- function(dataset, parameter, grouping_variable) {
  formula <- rlang::new_formula(rlang::enexpr(parameter), rlang::enexpr(grouping_variable))
  parameter <- dataset %>% rstatix::t_test(formula, paired = FALSE, detailed = TRUE) %>% rstatix::add_significance()
  return(parameter)
}

vars <- c("var1", "var2")
var_nms <- map(set_names(vars), as.name)

tests <- map(var_nms, ~ my_t_test(mydf, !! .x, category)) 
tests

#> $var1
#> # A tibble: 1 × 16
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    -7.92      54.5      62.5 var1  type1  type2     24    26    -0.919 0.363
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: df <dbl>, conf.low <dbl>, conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>, p.signif <chr>
#> 
#> $var2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 16
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    -9.74      99.9      110. var2  type1  type2     24    26     -1.19 0.239
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: df <dbl>, conf.low <dbl>, conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>, p.signif <chr>
```

Another way is to use base R's `reformulate` and make your function work with strings instead:

```r
my_t_test <- function(dataset, parameter, grouping_variable) {
  formula <- reformulate(grouping_variable, parameter) 
  parameter <- dataset %>% rstatix::t_test(formula, paired = FALSE, detailed = TRUE) %>% rstatix::add_significance()
  return(parameter)
}

vars <- c("var1", "var2")
tests <- map(vars, ~ my_t_test(mydf, .x, "category")) 
tests

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 16
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     10.1      52.7      42.6 var1  type1  type2     30    20      1.14 0.263
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: df <dbl>, conf.low <dbl>, conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>, p.signif <chr>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 16
#>   estimate estimate1 estimate2 .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic     p
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     13.5      98.4      85.0 var2  type1  type2     30    20      1.56 0.127
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: df <dbl>, conf.low <dbl>, conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>,
#> #   alternative <chr>, p.signif <chr>
```

Finally, regarding the approach with `lapply`: Here iterating over `mydf[ , vars]` causes the error since based on this input it is not possible to create a formula. In each iteration `i` the input is `mydf[ , vars][[i]]` and based on this input there is no way to create a formula. But we can use `lapply` with each of the approaches above.

Data from OP

```r
# make df 
mydf <- data.frame("category" = as.factor(sample(c("type1", "type2"), 50, replace = TRUE)),
                   "var1" = runif(50, min = 0, max = 100),
                   "var2" = runif(50, min = 50, max = 150))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>